# Awk selecting specific fields and requiring a variable at the same time

Tags: scripts, awk

I am trying to make an awk script that will take a file and then a word and then will output only the first and third fields if the first one contains that word so far the closest I have is

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 

print $3,$1~/chevy/
```

but this outputs all of both lines and then just puts a 0 or a 1 at the end if they have the word in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk programs always consist of pattern-action pairs. In your case, you want action `{print $1,$3}` when the record matches pattern `$1~/chevy/`. So

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 

$1~/chevy/ {print $1,$3}
```